# Passing variables from one class to an other in PhP

Tags: php, web-services, restful-url, restful-architecture

Hello I am trying to build my first restful web service and im using the instruction from lorna jane mitchell blog.

If the req comes through this Url : http://localhost:8888/lorna/index.php/tree/getpath?node_id=75
i call the function getpath passing node_id 
The function get path looks like this :

```
  class NestedSet
    {
       public function getPath($id) {

    $sql = "SELECT p." . $this->pk . ", p." . $this->name . " FROM ". $this->table . " n, " . $this->table . " p WHERE n.lft BETWEEN p.lft AND p.rgt AND n." . $this->pk ." = " . $id . " ORDER BY p.lft;";
       $result = $this->db->query($sql);
       if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
       return $this->error(1, true);
       }
       $path = array();
       $i = 0;
       while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $path[$i] = $row;
        $i++;
       }
      return $path;
     }

    }
```

Now i want to pass this variable $path to the class JsonView that looks like this :

```
    class JsonView extends ApiView {
public function render($path) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
    echo json_encode($path);
    return true;
   }
   }





   class ApiView {
     protected function addCount($data) {
     if(!empty($data)) {
        // do nothing, this is added earlier
     } else {
        $data['meta']['count'] = 0;
       }
        return $data;

     } 
     }
```

Any Idea on how can I pass the variable $path or any other variable through this JsonView Class.
Thank you very much for your time :)

UPDATE         This is the code for creating the nested class object

```
public function getAction($request) {
  $data = $request->parameters;

  if(isset($request->url_elements[2])) {

    switch ($request->url_elements[2]) {
      case 'getpath':

      $id = $data['node_id'];

      $nested = new NestedSet();
      $nested->getPath($id);

      $api = new JsonView(); 
      $api->render($path); 

      break;

      default:
      # code...
      break;
    }
  } else {
    $nested = new NestedSet(); 
    echo $nested->treeAsHtml();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create object of JsonView and then call the function render using that object.

```
$api = new JsonView;
$api->render($path);
```

Comment: @akhilp255 i tried it and i get this errors    Notice: Undefined variable: path in /Applications/MAMP/lorna/controllers/TreeController.php on line 66

Comment: Correction for the error you mentioned above. $path is only available inside the class. Value inside the path returns after calling the function getPath(). You have to save it in a variable and then pass to the next function. 

`$nested = new NestedSet();
$path = $nested->getPath($id);

$api = new JsonView(); 
$api->render($path);`

Comment: Yes now it Works :) thank you very much for your time